# Object in array is undefined

Tags: json, typescript

I receive JSON data from an API.

When I run below...

```
console.log(this.flexibleContent[1].tabs[0].links);
console.log(this.flexibleContent[1].tabs[0].countries);
console.log(this.flexibleContent[1].tabs[0].links[0].title);
console.log(this.flexibleContent[1].tabs[0].countries[0].link.title);
```

.. I receive this..

[image]

As you can see the third `console.log` logs `undefined` when I expect it to log `Business contact information`. However, it logs `Austria` just fine, and this is what baffles me.

I suspect the problem has to do with my models, as per below.

```
export class FlexibleContent {
    acf_fc_layout: string;
    video: string;
    photo: string;
    cover_text: string;
    tabs: Tab[];

    constructor(obj?: any) {
        Object.assign(this, obj);
    }
}

export class Tab {
    tab_name: string;
    header: string;
    ingress: string;
    text_area: string;
    links: Link[];
    countries: Country[];
}

export class Link {
    title: string;
    url: string;
    target: string;
}

export class Country {
    flag: string;
    link: Link;
}
```

Why is it successfully logging the title of a link in a `Country` but not the title of a link in a `Tab`?

Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code tries to access a non-existant property:

```
console.log(this.flexibleContent[1].tabs[0].links[0].title);
```

Your screenshot shows that there's a `link` property:

[image]

You wanted this:

```
console.log(this.flexibleContent[1].tabs[0].links[0].link.title);
```

Comment: links[0] should give me the first link in links. There is no 'link' property in links[0]. Only 'title', 'url' and 'target'.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
console.log(this.flexibleContent[1].tabs[0].links[0].link.title);
```

Comment: links[0] should give me the first link in links. There is no 'link' property in links[0]. Only 'title', 'url' and 'target'

Comment: What do you get if you log tabs[0].links[0]?